# JavaScript global variable value lost in a function

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a fairly simple question.

The value of my `operationVal` gets lost when it enters the click event and `if(operationVal == 0 )` returns `true`. But if i check `operationVal` just before the event it has the selected value. Furthermore, if i write `operation.options[operation.selectedIndex].value` instead of `operationVal` in if in the event, the value grabbed is the correct one instead.

I would be grateful if someone explained me why is that so. I'm assuming it has something to do with JavaScript scope, but it doesn't make sense to me.

```
const firstNumber = document.getElementById('tbFirstNumber');
const secondNumber = document.getElementById('tbSecondNumber');
const operation = document.getElementById('ddlOperation');
const operationVal = operation.options[operation.selectedIndex].value;
const btn = document.getElementById('btnExecute');
const display = document.getElementById('display');

let result = '';

const regNumbers = /[0-9]{1,}/;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(argument) {
  if (regNumbers.test(firstNumber.value) && regNumbers.test(secondNumber.value)) {
    if (operationVal == 0) {
      alert(operationVal);
      result = 'Operation has not been chosen';
    } else {
      switch (operationVal) {
        case 'add':
          result = 'Result is: ' + (firstNumber.value + secondNumber.value);
          break;
        default:
          // statements_def
          break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    result = 'Number entry is not correct.';
  };

  display.innerHTML = result;
});
```

Comment: callback function is asynchronous!

Comment: We don't have the full picture, but it looks like you are trying to read the user's selected choice before they've had an opportunity to make one?

Comment: @AndyG you are right. That was the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The following line:

```
operationVal = operation.options[operation.selectedIndex].value;
```

gets the selected value at the time this code executes, not at the *future* time when the user clicks the button.

The simple solution is to move this line inside the event listener callback function.

Answer (score 0):

> But if i check operationVal just before the event it has the selected
>   value. Furthermore, if i write
>   operation.options[operation.selectedIndex].value instead of
>   operationVal in if in the event, **the value grabbed is the correct one
>   instead**.

Looks like your value got changed before the `click` event

```
const operationVal = operation.options[operation.selectedIndex].value;
```

since above line has probably been executed while binding events on your page.

Once `operationVal` is set, it **won't get refreshed automatically** when you will select a different value from the drop-down.

You need to set this value again in the event handler

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(argument) {
  //observe this line
  operationVal = operation.options[operation.selectedIndex].value;
  if (regNumbers.test(firstNumber.value) && regNumbers.test(secondNumber.value)) {
    if (operationVal == 0) {
      alert(operationVal);
      result = 'Operation has not been chosen';
    } else {
      switch (operationVal) {
        case 'add':
          result = 'Result is: ' + (firstNumber.value + secondNumber.value);
          break;
        default:
          // statements_def
          break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    result = 'Number entry is not correct.';
  };

  display.innerHTML = result;
});
```

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks for a more detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

The `operarionVal` was not selected by the user when it is setted. So you have to put the attribution `const operationVal = operation.options[operation.selectedIndex].value;` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

`operationVal` value is set when you load the page. and is not updated with respect when your selectbox value changes 
therefore the value of `operationVal` remains constant

You need to move

```
const operationVal = operation.options[operation.selectedIndex].value;
```

to click event listner may solve the issue

```
const firstNumber = document.getElementById('tbFirstNumber');
const secondNumber = document.getElementById('tbSecondNumber');
const operation = document.getElementById('ddlOperation');
let operationVal = operation.options[operation.selectedIndex].value;
const btn = document.getElementById('btnExecute');
const display = document.getElementById('display');

let result = '';

const regNumbers = /[0-9]{1,}/;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(argument) {
  if (regNumbers.test(firstNumber.value) && regNumbers.test(secondNumber.value)) {
    operationVal = operation.options[operation.selectedIndex].value;
    if (operationVal == 0) {
      alert(operationVal);
      result = 'Operation has not been chosen';
    } else {
      switch (operationVal) {
        case 'add':
          result = 'Result is: ' + (firstNumber.value + secondNumber.value);
          break;
        default:
          // statements_def
          break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    result = 'Number entry is not correct.';
  };

  display.innerHTML = result;
});
```